# Tensorflow Object detection API : Turn a GPIO pin high when a specific class is detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I am using Tensorflow Object detection API to detect objects on respberry pi, it is real time object detection, and I have it working fine. It can draw the bounding box with label and the conference score of the class it detected. So here is my question:

How can I turn a GPIO pin to high when a specific class is detected, lets say the specific class is 'person', and I want pin 11 to be high, how do I do it?

Here is the code that I think is related:

```
# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

        # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=3,
            min_score_thresh=0.40)

        cv2.putText(frame,"FPS: {0:.2f}".format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),font,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
        cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)
```

Could `np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)` be a way to get the detected class?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the GPIO via the  /sys/class/gpio interface. In my case I use another embedded system. But it should work more or less the same. I am using bash commands. But you could easily replace these by Python file operations.

```
ubuntu@localhost:/sys/class/gpio$ ls
export  gpiochip1008  gpiochip1016  gpiochip890  unexport
```

There are can be several gpio interfaces. To use the interfaces:

enable the first two bits

```
echo 1008 > export
echo 1009 > export
```

This will create a number for new IO files:

```
root@localhost:/sys/class/gpio# ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Feb 11 17:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 45 root root    0 Feb 11 16:45 ..
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Feb 11 17:08 export
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Feb 11 16:53 gpio1008 -> ../../devices/soc0/amba_pl/41200000.gpio/gpiochip1/gpio/gpio1008
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Feb 11 17:02 gpio1009 -> ../../devices/soc0/amba_pl/41200000.gpio/gpiochip1/gpio/gpio1009
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Feb 11 17:05 unexport
```

Set the direction of the outputs to 'out' ('in' is the default)

```
echo out > gpio1008/direction
echo out > gpio1009/direction
```

Make the pins high:

```
echo 1 > gpio1016/value
echo 1 > gpio1017/value
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter detection scores with .3 or something than if detection classes has that class in filtered indexes you can send high to pin

```
from gpiozero import LED

led = LED(11) #pin you plug led
filter=0.3 #filter of scores if you decrease it program finds more item
selected_class=4 #you want to find class
isledhigh=False
...
    makeledhigh=False
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
    for i in range(int(num[0])):
        if classes[i]==selected_class and scores[i]>=filter:
            makeledhigh=True
    if makeledhigh and !isledhigh:
        led.on()
        isledhigh=True
    if isledhigh and !makeledhigh:
        led.off()
        isledhigh=False
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite straightforward:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)

if object_detected_class==1:
    GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)

else: #other class
    GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
```